# How to hide page header band on last page

Tags: variables, jasper-reports

I think I am having a problem with evaluation time.  In this example, you see the variable `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")` reflecting the last page correctly; it updates correctly.  But when I use it for the "printWhenExpression" of a detail band field (experiment) or for the page header band (my goal) it does not work.

I am using "page" evaluation time throughout which seems to work for the variable itself.  But the printWhenExpressions are not working using this variable.

Here is my xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from users]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="userName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="238" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}
            .get("LastPageNumber"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["please don't print on last page - page header"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="175" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["last page  variable is: " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}
            .get("LastPageNumber"))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="2" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page header"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement x="381" y="0" width="174" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["last page variable is: " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}
            .get("LastPageNumber"))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{userName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement x="119" y="0" width="191" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}
            .get("LastPageNumber"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["please don't print on last page - detail"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="188" y="21" width="100" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("LastPageNumber",
    $V{PAGE_NUMBER}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement x="380" y="2" width="174" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["last page variable is: " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}
            .get("LastPageNumber"))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

My solution was to make two reports (one for the last page) and then join them (jasperPrints) using the array list option for he jasper exporter:

```
List jasperPrintList = new ArrayList();

JasperPrint jasperPrint1 =
        JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            jasperReport1,
            parameters,
            c
    );


JasperPrint jasperPrint2 =
        JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            jasperReport2,
            parameters,
            c
    );
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint1);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint2);
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
ByteArrayOutputStream byte_report = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "test_report_name");
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, byte_report);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Otherwise asked -- is there a way to have a "last page header" band that works like the "last page footer"?  on last page, "last page footer" prints and "page footer" does not.  that is what i need, except for the header....

Comment: When evaluating the header, Jasper reports does not yet know whether it is the last page. When evaluating the footer, though, it does. Thus, i wouldn't expect a `lastPageHeader` to exist.

Comment: yes, i went the route of making the past page a separate report, putting the two jasperPrints into an array list, and exporting the array to PDF.   i know it is hard to figure the number of pages when filling a report, but even if you simply filled it twice (this for the jasper lib team) give that as an option to your users who are willing the pay that perf price to have a lastPage boolean variable at fill time! )))

Comment: *if you simply filled it twice* - that wouldn't suffice in general. Imagine a slightly different case from yours, someone wants a header only on the last page. A first run indicates that the file has n pages. Thus, in the second run, a header is put on page n. Unfortunately that header takes up some space which in the first run was used by the page content. This might make the process require an additional page which becomes the really last page (as such getting a header). Now you have headers on the final two pages...

Comment: i understabnd.  this is a larger software architecture question, and a very interesting one, i might add. i could be wrong )), but it seems that the only way to identify the last page of a report is to fill the whole report; of course, if we/jasper chose this direction we could optimize the first pass (e.g. not writing all the bytes of an image). as for your example (nice catch), clearly even for the first run, the last page would need to be run twice if a last page header was used in the design...